# c++ error: invalid types ‘int[int]’ for array subscript for single dimensional array

Tags: c++, c++17

I am trying to write a program to find prefix sum. It is showing error: invalid types 'int[int] for array subscript for single dimensional array [code1](https://ideone.com/RgIfSE)

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

long long a[(int)1e5 + 50];
int n;

void buildPrefixSum() { // O(n)
   for(int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
       a[i] += a[i - 1];
   }

}

int getSum(int i, int j) { // O(1)
   int sum = a[j];
   if(i > 0) sum -= a[i - 1];
   return sum;
}

int main()
{
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);cin.tie(0);cout.tie(0);
    int t,a,b;
    cin >> n;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> a[i];
    }
    buildPrefixSum();
    cin >> t;
    while(t--)
    {
        cin >> a >> b;
        cout << getSum(a,b) << "\n";
    }
}
```

But when I change the main function to this, the code runs properly.[code2](https://ideone.com/M459dW)

```
int main() {
    cin >> n;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> a[i];
    }
    buildPrefixSum();
    int q;
    cin >> q;
    while(q-- > 0) {
        int a, b;
        cin >> a >> b;
        cout << getSum(a, b) << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I don't understand the difference between the two codes. Can anyone please clarify the mistake I made in the main function of the first code?

Comment: Look at where you're declaring `a` and what types you're declaring.

Comment: In the first snippet, in `main()`: `int t,a,b;` The local variable `a` eclipses the global variable with same name. (The global is still there but you cannot access it in the local scope.)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31816096/1387438

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you *first* code block, your `long long` array `a` is being "shadowed" (hidden) by the `a` in the line:

```
int t,a,b;
```

You'll find the problem boils down to this:

```
int main() {
    int a;
    a[0] = 7; // error: invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript
}
```

In your *second* code block, the declaration of the non-array `a` doesn't happen until *after* you've populated the array `a` - the shadowing only exists within the `while` loop and therefore does not raise an error.

I suspect this problem may not have occurred had you just used decent variable names :-)